# View disrupts on Window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, window

I've created a page using squares. The squares combine to make a particular word. But when I resize the window, the squares disrupt their place in a haphazard way. How I can change my `CSS` or `javascript` so that the squares retain their original positions on window resize?

You can view the page at : http://www.tryst-iitd.com/13/beta

I've included the following code to take care of the resizing, still the problem remains unsolved.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var screenWidth = $(window).width() + "px";
    var screenHeight = $(window).height() + "px";
    $("#container").css({
        width: screenWidth,
        height:screenHeight,
    });
    $(window).resize( function () {
        var screenWidth = $(window).width() + "px";
        var screenHeight = $(window).height() + "px";
        $("#container").css({
            width: screenWidth,
            height:screenHeight,
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The square is disrupted because the width of the container is adjusted automatically whenever you resize your window. Set a fix value or set a minimum width for the square and container should fix the problem. The square width is in %.

Also, the window resize event itself is useless because the div (id=container) is adjusted according to the width of the body tag

Comment: So, can you suggest a solution in a more broad approach?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with your page. If you want your page to not have the square disrupted ie a fixed width/height, then set the container width to 1000px for example (and remove the resize event in javascript) OR if you want your page to be a full-screen that works on all resolution page then you got to modify the width/height of the square dynamically and have a min-width/min-height set

Comment: After doing some tests, the minimum width of the container should be 1237px. If you want it to be less, you got to reduce the size of your squares

Answer (score 0):

Set the position and size of your squares in percentages and your resize code will works fine.

Also, set the `min-width`/`min-height` CSS properties will prevent your squares from being too small.

Comment: There is no position regarding the squares. They are all in % regarding the height and width with `float` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your css margins are fixed width, so even if squares width are in %, margins causes this issues.
As an example, try disabling `wrap1` and `wrapalphabet` css classes, you will see that your design will be much more responsive.

You probably have to rethink the way you deal with margin/padding to get the results you expect.